# eclipse seeing ivy-controlled property files

Tags: eclipse, ivy

We're using ant, ivy and eclipse.  We have some projects that deploy (publish) not only a jar file but a property file or two.  Using ant/ivy we can reference jar files from the repository (without actually moving them) and likewise, eclipse sees these jar files in its class path via the ivy eclipse plugin.

How, however, do we get a .properties file onto the class path?  Currently, ant will deploy them to a build_tests directory and both ant and eclipse can pick them up from there when running unit and integration tests.  But if eclipse ever does a build, it wipes that build_tests directory out and we've lost all the property files.

Not really a problem with ant because a follow-on ant build will just put them back, but eclipse suddenly starts failing when running the tests.  Is there any way to get a properties file in the repository onto the eclipse class path?  Alternatively, can eclipse 'deploy' any necessary property files needed by the test configuration?

Answer (score 0):

With [IvyDE](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde) you can manage non java dependencies, and put them any place you want, just like the ant task `retrieve`. To get it working, see the documentation:

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/non-java.html